# Switch among multiple URLs in same tab Using Java

Tags: java, uri

I need to open a Url in the browser and open a different Url in the same tab using Java. I'm using Eclipse MARS 2. 
I tried this:

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;

    public class JavaApp 
    {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("google.com");
    }
}
```

but it returns this 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SovMY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a WebDriver.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

I don't think there's a way to do it in vanilla Java.